# WPF GroupStyle in a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `DataTemplate` defined in another file. This template contains a `DataGrid`, which I need to have groups within.

**Fragment of templates XAML**:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplate">
    <DataGrid ...>
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="SomeGroupingStyle" />
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        ...
    </DataGrid>
```

The group style is defined in the **main XAML**, where this template gets attached to:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SomeSource" Source="{Binding Elements}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <GroupStyle x:Key="SomeGroupingStyle">

                        ...
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <!-- Here comes template -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/path;component/UI/ViewTemplates.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

After I launch my app, exception accurs:

```
Exception: Die Ressource mit dem Namen "SomeGroupingStyle" kann nicht gefunden werden.
```

what means, that DataGridGroupStyle has not been found. Referring to this style as to DynamicResource doesn't work as well.

How can I use GroupStyle in a DataTemplate, that is stored in another file?

**UPD:** Seems like my DataTemplate does not see any resources from the main layout at all — `SomeSource` causes the same error, when I move `SomeGroupingStyle` to the same file with the template.

And here is how the `DataTemplate` gets shown in the **main XAML**:

```
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding}">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSomeCondition}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SomeTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAnotherCondition}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource OtherTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
```

**UPD 2**: The `DataTemplates` don't see any `StaticResources` of the parent at all.